# Read Alphanumeric with REGEX - C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, alphanumeric

I have this code and its posible to read numbers with regex (from an XML File), but i want to read an Alphanumeric string , and get the value as the numeric one:

```
string c1 = File.ReadAllText("C://XMLS/128839_SAG101208EJ4_10006_16_13-01-2017.xml");

           // i get 163.23 from the xml " subTotal="163.23" "

            Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<=subTotal="")[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?="")");

            //Check if matches
            var res = rx.Match(c1);

            if (res.Success)
            {
                var res2 = res.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(res2);
            }
```

and here is the string i want to get >>  UUID="a25101f7-65e7-49be-a8de-c8d7be8ec32d"  and as you can see it also has " - " between letters

Thank you

PS : I don´t want to use  XML libraries , just REGEX

Comment: .net has built-in functionality to work with xml. you don't need any libraries for that

Comment: Yes i know , but i dont want to use cml functionallities , just regex

Comment: Is there a good reason for reinventing the wheel? Other than "I don't want to"

Comment: Yes , i already had troubles with .net built in , because the format of the xml (what i use) change depend the situation ( refering to nodes ), thats what i want regex , to just read the file and find that specific match

Comment: You can use XPath to select a specific node/attribute with dependency to the global xml structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the UUID you can use this pattern:

`[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}`